# Transformation of received data

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I get data like this

```
[
    {
        "channel_number": 1,
        "id_channel": "св-1312",
        "consumption": 1231,
        "date": 01
    },
    {
        "channel_number": 1,
        "id_channel": "св-1312",
        "consumption": 1234,
        "date": 02
    },
    {
        "channel_number": 1,
        "id_channel": "св-1312",
        "consumption": 1234,
        "date": 03
    },
    {
        "channel_number": 2,
        "id_channel": "св-1314",
        "consumption": 800,
        "date": 01
    },
    {
        "channel_number": 2,
        "id_channel": "св-1314",
        "consumption": 823,
        "date": 02
    },
    {
        "channel_number": 2,
        "id_channel": "св-1314",
        "consumption": 1233,
        "date": 03
    }
]
```

I need to make the data for each date be merged into one object.

Like this:

```
[
  {
    date: 01,
    channels: [
      {
        channel_number: 1
        consumption: 1000
      },
      {
        channel_number: 2
        consumption: 2000
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    date: 02,
    channels: [
      {
        channel_number: 1
        consumption: 1000
      },
      {
        channel_number: 2
        consumption: 2000
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

The data comes from the server, so there may be more dates and channels.

I did the following but it doesn't give me what I need:

```
let newArr = arr.map((el: any, i: any) => {
    return {
      date: el.date,
      channels: [{ channel_number: el.channel_number, consumption: el.consumption }],
    };
  });
```

I've tried other ways, but it doesn't work. It's just that for the first time such a transformation was needed, but I have no experience

Please, help me.

Comment: try `array.prototype.group()` to group by `date`, then with `Object.entries` of it and a `array.prototype.map()`

Comment: As the name suggest `Array.prototype.map()` perform a 1-to-1 mapping; as you need to group and transform the items in your original  array, you might be better off with `Array.prototype.reduce()`

Comment: @secan could you describe in more detail please?

Comment: @wendt88 could you describe in more detail please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `Array.prototype.reduce()`:

```js
const input = [{
    "channel_number": 1,
    "id_channel": "св-1312",
    "consumption": 1231,
    "date": 01
  },
  {
    "channel_number": 1,
    "id_channel": "св-1312",
    "consumption": 1234,
    "date": 02
  },
  {
    "channel_number": 1,
    "id_channel": "св-1312",
    "consumption": 1234,
    "date": 03
  },
  {
    "channel_number": 2,
    "id_channel": "св-1314",
    "consumption": 800,
    "date": 01
  },
  {
    "channel_number": 2,
    "id_channel": "св-1314",
    "consumption": 823,
    "date": 02
  },
  {
    "channel_number": 2,
    "id_channel": "св-1314",
    "consumption": 1233,
    "date": 03
  }
];

const output = input.reduce((acc, item) => {
  // 1. You check whether the accumulator already contains an object
  //    with the same date of the item you are currently considering
  let accItem = acc.find(_item => _item.date === item.date);

  if (accItem) {
    // 2a. if it does, you update that object by pushing into the `channels` array
    //     the data from your item
    accItem.channels.push({
      channel_number: item.channel_number,
      consumption: item.consumption
    });
  } else {
    // 2b. if it does NOT, you create a new object from the item
    //     and you push it into the accumulator
    acc.push({
      date: item.date,
      channels: [{
        channel_number: item.channel_number,
        consumption: item.consumption
      }]
    })
  }
  
  // 3. finally you return the updater accumulator and repeat point 1 and 2
  //    for the following item in your input array
  return acc
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

### EDIT: Alternative solution to avoid nested loops

Actually, now that I think about it, if your input array can contain a lot of items, using `Array.prototype.find()` inside `Array.prototype.reduce()` might not be the best solution in terms of performances because you have nested loops.

Although it is less "linear", this solution might be better performing:

```js
const input = [{
    "channel_number": 1,
    "id_channel": "св-1312",
    "consumption": 1231,
    "date": 01
  },
  {
    "channel_number": 1,
    "id_channel": "св-1312",
    "consumption": 1234,
    "date": 02
  },
  {
    "channel_number": 1,
    "id_channel": "св-1312",
    "consumption": 1234,
    "date": 03
  },
  {
    "channel_number": 2,
    "id_channel": "св-1314",
    "consumption": 800,
    "date": 01
  },
  {
    "channel_number": 2,
    "id_channel": "св-1314",
    "consumption": 823,
    "date": 02
  },
  {
    "channel_number": 2,
    "id_channel": "св-1314",
    "consumption": 1233,
    "date": 03
  }
];

const tempObj = input.reduce((obj, item) => {
  if (obj[item.date]) {
    obj[item.date].channels.push({
      channel_number: item.channel_number,
      consumption: item.consumption
    });
  } else {
    obj[item.date] = {
      date: item.date,
      channels: [{
        channel_number: item.channel_number,
        consumption: item.consumption
      }]
    }
  }

  return obj;
}, {});

const output = Object.values(tempObj);

console.log(output);
```

If you notice that in production the original solution is too slow, you might want to try this one and see if things improve.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, it doesn't use a map but it seems to produce the output you require.

```js
const arr = [
    {
        "channel_number": 1,
        "id_channel": "св-1312",
        "consumption": 1231,
        "date": 01
    },
    {
        "channel_number": 1,
        "id_channel": "св-1312",
        "consumption": 1234,
        "date": 02
    },
    {
        "channel_number": 1,
        "id_channel": "св-1312",
        "consumption": 1234,
        "date": 03
    },
    {
        "channel_number": 2,
        "id_channel": "св-1314",
        "consumption": 800,
        "date": 01
    },
    {
        "channel_number": 2,
        "id_channel": "св-1314",
        "consumption": 823,
        "date": 02
    },
    {
        "channel_number": 2,
        "id_channel": "св-1314",
        "consumption": 1233,
        "date": 03
    }
];  

var newObj = {};
arr.forEach(element => {
    // Check if this date already exists, if not then create it
    if (newObj[element.date] == null) {
        newObj[element.date] = { 'date' : element.date, 'channels' : [] };
    }
    newObj[element.date]['channels'].push({ 'channel_number' : element.channel_number, 'consumption' : element.consumption });
});
console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: The OP expects an array as output, not an object. By the way, naming a variable `newArr` and initialize it as an object can be pretty confusing. ;)

Comment: @secan Very true, I missed that he wanted an array, I read the word object in the question. I was trying to match the variable names from his example, hence the badly named variable.

Answer (score 0):

I used `reduce` instead of `group`
`date` is defined as number with 0 prefixed, so it gets cut
optionaly add a `sort` if u wish to sort by date

```js
    const data = [
    {

            "channel_number": 1,
            "id_channel": "св-1312",
            "consumption": 1231,
            "date": 01
        },
        {
            "channel_number": 1,
            "id_channel": "св-1312",
            "consumption": 1234,
            "date": 02
        },
        {
            "channel_number": 1,
            "id_channel": "св-1312",
            "consumption": 1234,
            "date": 03
        },
        {
            "channel_number": 2,
            "id_channel": "св-1314",
            "consumption": 800,
            "date": 01
        },
        {
            "channel_number": 2,
            "id_channel": "св-1314",
            "consumption": 823,
            "date": 02
        },
        {
            "channel_number": 2,
            "id_channel": "св-1314",
            "consumption": 1233,
            "date": 03
        }
    ];
    let grouped = data.reduce((group, d) => {
      const { date } = d;
      group[date] = group[date] ?? [];
      group[date].push(d);
      return group;
    }, {});
    let maped = Object.entries(grouped)
        .map(([date, value]) => ({
        date,
        channels: value
            .map(d => ({
            channel_number: d.channel_number,
            consumption: d.consumption
          }))
      }));
    console.log(maped);
```